# Is open map needed to be continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X,Y$ be the topological spaces and $f:\ X\to Y$. Then $f$ is continuous of $X$ if and only if preimage of any open set in $Y$ is also an open set in $X$.

An open map $f:\ X\to Y$ is a map that takes any open set in $X$ to an open set in $Y$. In general topology, we are introduced with some famous results of the open map. However, I haven't found any result states that open map implies continuous so far. I wonder if there're some counter examples for an open map that is not continuous ? Thanks.

Comment: If $f^{-1}$ exists, then [$f$ is continuous if and only if $ f^{−1}$ is an open map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877445/is-the-inverse-of-a-continuous-function-an-open-map)

Comment: For a function $f : X \to Y$ the concepts of being *continuous* and being *open* are independent. See Ali Mezher's answer. However, the definition "An open map $f:\ X\to Y$ is a map that takes any open set in $X$ to an open set in $Y$" may be a bit misleading because many authors use the word *map* as a synonym  for *continuous function*. With this interpretation an open map would be continuous by definition. By the way, in topology discontinuous functions do not play an important role, so openness usually occurs as an additional attribute of a continuous function.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the spaces $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, and $Y = \mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. Define the map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ by $f(x) = x$, which is the identity map.

- $f$ is an open map: Since $Y$ has the discrete topology, every subset of $Y$ is considered open, including the images of open sets in $X$ under $f$. Therefore, $f$ maps open sets to open sets.
- $f$ is not continuous: In the discrete topology on $Y$, single points $\{y\}$ are open, but their preimages under $f$, which are also single points $\{x\}$ in $X$, are not open in the standard topology of $X$. Hence, $f$ fails the definition of continuity because there exists an open set in $Y$ whose preimage is not open in $X$.

This counterexample demonstrates that an open map is not necessarily continuous, highlighting the independence of these two topological properties.